# How does UIApplication take an event from the top of event queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I read this in the official doc:

First, the singleton UIApplication object takes an event from the top of the queue and dispatches it for handling.

How does this happen??
Also in the doc there is this section:

An App Receives Touches in the Touch-Handling Methods:

During a multitouch sequence, an app sends these messages when there are new or changed touches for a given touch phase; it calls the

touchesBegan:withEvent: method when one or more fingers touch down on the screen.....

**Can somebody explain this line"..an app sends these messages...". It is very ambigious as to which "messages" are being talked about in the doc!!!!**

Doc link:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2

Also, how internally does the UIApplication send the events to keyWindow??
Does it use sendEvent or does it have code something like

`[[self keyWindow] touchesBegan:touches
           withEvent:event];`

Answer (score 0):

> How does this happen??

A queue is a first-in-first-out data structure. You put things in one end, and you take them out on the other. Exactly what method gets called to do this depends on how the OS happens to implement the event queue, but in the end it really doesn't matter at all, and in fact it may be done differently in different versions of the operating system. *The event queue is an implementation detail, so you shouldn't make any assumptions about how it works.*

> Can somebody explain this line"..an app sends these messages...".

It just means that the app calls certain methods on certain objects. In Objective-C, "sending a message" is another way of saying "calling a particular object's instance method." If you have:

```
[foo bar];
```

you are sending message `bar` to `foo`.

Comment: I know the sending message concept....i am confused as to the logic in that line. Does it say that the UIApplication object sends messages like touchesBegan:withEvent: ? what i learned was that UIResponder subclasses respond to events using methods like touchesBegan:withEvent: ......so what exactly does it mean?? which messages are being talked about in the doc ?

Comment: Sure. Responders implement `-touchesBegan:...` etc., but those implementations don't mean much if they never get called, right? The application is responsible for dispatching events. It's continually checking for new events, and when it gets one it finds the object that should respond and sends it an appropriate message. In some cases (like a key pressed on a keyboard) it uses the first responder; in other cases (like a touch) it'll use [hit testing](http://apple.co/1HrlT3X) to find the view that contains the touch.